# Convert a HashMap into IntArray while filtering some keys

Tags: collections, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a simple algorithm in `Kotlin` which finds only unique numbers in an array.

I cannot figuring out how to convert the `map` into the `uniqueArray` with elements which values equals to 1.

```
val array: IntArray = intArrayOf(4, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5)
val map: HashMap<Int, Int> = HashMap()

for (x in array) map.merge(x, 1, {v, _ -> v + 1})

// convert the map into an IntArray
val uniqueArray: IntArray = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and destructure entry into key and value as below:

```
val uniqueArray: IntArray = map
            .filter { (k, v) -> v == 1 }
            .keys
            .toIntArray()
```

Comment: worked out. thx! does it possible to replace `.map { (k, v) -> k }` with `.keys`?

Comment: It is! I will edit my answer, thanks for noticing that :)

Comment: it was in an answer which is currently deleted)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete algorithm that doesn't involve counting instances:

```
val input = intArrayOf(4, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5)

val duplicates = emptySet<Int>().toMutableSet()
val result = emptySet<Int>().toMutableSet()

for (it in input) {
    if (duplicates.contains(it)) {
        continue
    }
    if (!result.add(it)) {
        result.remove(it)
        duplicates.add(it)
    }
}
```